# Azure Devops Error : "unknown field "imagePullPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am using `Azure Devops`, and getting unknown field `imagePullPolicy"`in `io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec` while doing `helm install` :

> 2019-07-05T10:49:11.0064690Z ##[warning]Can't find command extension for ##vso[telemetry.command]. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
>
> 2019-07-05T09:56:41.1837910Z Error: validation failed: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "imagePullPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec
>
> 2019-07-05T09:56:41.1980030Z ##[error]Error: validation failed: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "imagePullPolicy" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec
>
> deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: {{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.fullname" . }}
labels:
{{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
    maxSurge: 1
    maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
template:
    metadata:
    labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
    containers:
    - image:  {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        name:  {{ .Chart.Name }}
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
        value: {{ .Values.environment }}
        resources:
        requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}
        limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}
        livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
            path: /api/version
            port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 90
        timeoutSeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 15
        readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
            path: /api/version
            port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        timeoutSeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 15      
        ports:
        - containerPort:  80
        name:  http
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/config
        name: {{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.name" . }}
        readOnly: true
    volumes:
        - name: {{ include "clusterfitusecaseapihelm.name" . }}
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regsecret
```

[image]

> Tried this also but failed:

[image]

Comment: I have installed helm version 2.14.1

Comment: show the pod manifest, but I think it shouldn't be under spec, it should be under spec.containers

Comment: On my local kubernetes cluster (docker-for-desktop), its working fine.

Comment: Looks like the alignment / location issue - `imagePullPolicy: Always` should come under containers: tag, next to image:.

Comment: See the pic, its already under container.

Comment: Move line# 59 below to line# 24 (next to image:) with two spaces prefix.

Comment: Tried and failes, in yaml level matters but sibling rank does not matter, so sibling can be anywhere at same level.

Comment: No Sir, now swap image and imagePullPolicy lines. line#24 should go down below image:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196042/discussion-between-prakash-krishna-and-vatan-soni).

Comment: Thanks man..

Actually I used default generated snippets by vs-code with kubernetes extension. Need to be careful when using snippets at vs code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`imagePullPolicy` is a property of a [Container object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#container-v1-core), not a Pod object, so you need to move this setting inside the `containers:` list (next to `image:`).

Comment: Yes, its already set as containers property, please check again my given yaml.

Comment: no, like i said it should be under containers, not spec

Comment: Actually I used default generated snippets by vs-code with kubernetes extension. Need to be careful when using snippets at vs code.